# Encryption of message concatenated with encrypted message

Tags: encryption, rsa

Is there a possibility to encrypt a message that is a concatenation of an encrypted message and another message ( encrypt_message + message )?

Comment: You can compute the concatenation of two strings (one of which is an encrypted message), and then encrypt that concatenation.  That is obvious; what did you mean to ask?

Comment: Do you fear double encryption will cancel?

Comment: Of course you can add as many layers of encryption as you like. It can be insecure if done poorly, like encrypting again with same key and nonce using stream ciphers (incl block ciphers in stream modes like CTR/GCM/CCM or OFB) which cancels out encryption altogether. But generally, it is safe

Comment: @poncho yes , this what i mean

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible. One can encrypt any message, no matter how it is formed.